# R URL encoding issue?

Tags: r, urlencode

I'm trying to get a data table off of a website using the RCurl package.  My code works successfully for the URL that you get to by clicking through the website:

http://statsheet.com/mcb/teams/air-force/game_stats/

Once you try to select previous years (which I want); my code no longer works.

Example link:
http://statsheet.com/mcb/teams/air-force/game_stats?season=2012-2013

I'm guessing this has something to do with the reserved symbol(s) in the year specific address.  I've tried URLencode as well as manually encoding the address but that hasn't worked either.

My code:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

#Define URL
theurl <-URLencode("http://statsheet.com/mcb/teams/air-force/game_stats?season=2012-    
2013", reserved=TRUE)

webpage <- getURL(theurl)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)

pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

# Extract table header and contents
tablehead <- xpathSApply(pagetree, "//*/table[1]/thead[1]/tr[2]/th", xmlValue)
results <- xpathSApply(pagetree,"//*/table[1]/tbody/tr/td", xmlValue)

content <- as.data.frame(matrix(results, ncol = 19, byrow = TRUE))

testtablehead <- c("W/L","Opponent",tablehead[c(2:18)])
names(content) <- testtablehead
```

The relevant error that R returns:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Could not resolve host: http%3a%2f%2fstatsheet.com%2fmcb%2fteams%2fair-  
force%2fgame_stats%3fseason%3d2012-2013; No data record of requested type
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Using `reserved=FALSE` gives the same error?

Comment: Putting reserved=FALSE causes R to get hung-up while executing the geturl command

Update:  It actually ran out that time but gave the error:
    Error in matrix(results, ncol = 19, byrow = TRUE) : 
    'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the unneeded encoding and download of the url:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://statsheet.com/mcb/teams/air-force/game_stats?season=2012-2013"

pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

Comment: That gives me the error `Error in UseMethod("xmlNamespaceDefinitions") : 
  no applicable method for 'xmlNamespaceDefinitions' applied to an object of class "NULL"`  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get that error. So it may be a bug in XML, or one of us doesn't have the latest version XML.

Comment: I don't get that error either.  I am using XML ‘3.98.1.1’ and "R version 3.0.2 Patched (2013-11-25 r64299)" on Windows 8.1 .